# python checkbox event trigger

Tags: python, checkbox, wxpython

I want to trigger a button event without having to click on it(manually)

```
self.cb1 = wx.CheckBox(self, -1, "pewpew")
self.Bind(wx.EVT_CHECKBOX, self.lg, self.cb1)
self.cb1.SetValue(True)
```

I tried the above code , it just initializes the button on checked but it does not trigger the event function. Is it possible to trigger the function manually ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use `wx.CommandEvent` and `wx.PostEvent`:

```
import wx

class TestFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id=-1, title=title)
        text = wx.StaticText(self, label=title)

        self.cb1 = wx.CheckBox(self, -1, "pewpew")
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CHECKBOX, self.lg, self.cb1)

        evt = wx.CommandEvent(wx.EVT_CHECKBOX.typeId, self.cb1.GetId())
        wx.PostEvent(self, evt)


    def lg(self, in_event):
        print in_event
        print 'In lg'


app = wx.App()
frame = TestFrame(None, "Hello, world!")
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: i used something relevant but this is ok too